# linux: finding cause of realtime signal

Tags: linux, signals, handler

I have a linux test prog with some custom drivers. When running, my prog will suddenly exit with "realtime signal 5". The core dump shows the signal being handled by a thread that was in a nanosleep call, so I guess it's an asynchronous signal coming from *somewhere*.
Can anyone recommend a strategy for tracking down the origin of the signal? eg are there specific functions in the kernel I can add some logging to (send_sig maybe?). Thanks.

Comment: Specific version of Linux? Platform? Lots of context missing here.

Comment: Apologies for vagueness. 3.2 kernel, ARM platform.